# Expose Docker Port through my server and Tailscale

Tags: tailscale

I have a linux ubuntu server running several docker services. I also have tailscale installed and running on my server. I can reach the Tailscale IP of the server and ssh into it but I cant reach the docker services from my remote connection.

i.e. ssh 100.100.161.62 works fine but 100.100.161.62:8080 is unreachable.

Can anyone shed some light on how I can make these ports accessible?

Comment: Are the containers' ports publish to `100.100.161.62` (or `0.0.0.0`)? You could try ensuring that the container using `8080` has `run ... --publish=0.0.0.0:8080:8080/tcp ...`

Comment: I solved this with a fresh installation of tailscale I now need to figure out how to put my docker containers behind a vpn

Answer (score 0):

Solved with fresh installation of Tailscale